# Text translation API is translating the URL

Tags: api, text, translation, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator

I am trying to translate using microsoft cognitive text translation API:

Text to be translated is Your ticket with number INC123456 has been created. Following is the link, https://microsofttest.service-now.com/sp?id=ticket&table=incident&sys_id=aisuoiqwq1233444.

// Translating from english to telugu

This is getting translated into:

నెంబరు INC20534102 మీ టిక్కెట్ సృష్టించబడింది. దిగువ లింక్, [https://microsofttest.service-now.com/sp? id = టిక్కెట్ & పట్టిక = ఘటన & sys_id = aisuoiqwq1233444] (https://microsofttest.service-now.com/sp? id = టిక్కెట్ & పట్టిక = ఘటన & sys_id = aisuoiqwq1233444).

How can I prevent link from getting translated?

Comment: I had a quick look and cannot see a way to do that. Maybe you could raise an issue on microsoft side (https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/558796-translator-api)

Answer (score 0):

It is stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/prevent-translation) that you can tag content so that it isn't translated using several methods.

I think the best method for your scenario is tagging your content with `notranslate` as per the example below:

```
<div class="notranslate">This will not be translated.</div>
<div>This will be translated. </div>
```

You can either allow the user to edit the content using HTML, but I think the most essential solution would be to write a function to search for URLs in the content and automatically add this `notranslate` tag to it and do the magic!